# WindowsPhone 8 Emulator has stopped my internet from working

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Yesterday I installed WP8 SDK and built a simple hello world app, next time when i logged on to my laptop the internet was not working and i still cannot get it to work. In network adapter settings there is a connection to emulator and one is for my connection to wifi. It looks like wp emulator has messed with internet settings etc.

Please help.

Regards

Comment: Can the emulator use the internet? Try browsing through the Windows Phone Internet Explorer and let me know.

Comment: Yes windowsphone emulator works fine with internet, I opened some sites and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using manual settings for wifi or you internet use `DHCP`.
Using `DCHP` works for me as windows phone emulator creates switches and change your internet settings.

I hope this will work for you.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a tutorial [How to enable DHCP in windows?](http://mywindows8.org/how-to-turn-on-dhcp-in-windows-8/)

Comment: My connection is already set to use DHCP, I have checked it. :(

Comment: I don't have any idea then. Mine was not working when giving manual address but when I switch to DHCP then it works for me.

Comment: After uninstalling SDK, I right clicked on my wifi in adapter settings and removed it from bridge connection, now it seems to work

Comment: deleting the switches will have also worked. To develop WP8 apps I use device instead of emulator. As emulator sucks